# How to configure RootLayout props correctly

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am learning Next.js, and I am kind stuck as this

```
interface IProps { children: React.ReactNode, navItems: Root}

const RootLayout:React.FC<IProps> =({ children , navItems}: IProps) => {
    return (
        <section>
          This is Layout
          <Sitenav  navItems={navItems}/>
             {children}
        </section>
      )
}
export default RootLayout;

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const navItems = await getNavigationData();
  return {
    props: {navItems }
  };
}
```

How can I pass {children} from getStaticProps to RootLayout function so that navItem is not received as children.props.xxx.xx . Any clue helps.

Comment: if you are using experimental next13 app directory,  you dont have `getStaticProps` in server components. if you are not, `getStaticProps` works only in pages